# Conditional replacement of a data.frame column with matrix values. VLOOKUP in R

Tags: r, matrix, dataframe, vlookup

I have a very simple doubt in R but still I cannot find the solution in previous answers for what I need, or I missed it. I want a sort of vlookup (like Excel) formula but only for specific rows in a dataframe. Let’s say I have a data frame like the following:

```
    id obs year   a1    a2        b1     b2         c
   604  43 2003   NA    NA        NA     NA        NA
   605  43 2004   NA    NA        NA     NA        NA
   606  43 2005 9000  6421   1748365 0.1616  36872152
   769  55 2003   NA    NA        NA     NA        NA
   770  55 2004   NA    NA        NA     NA        NA
   771  55 2005 2500 12449        NA     NA 125992307
   844  61 2003 1800 11633 157977428 0.0089  69901689
   845  61 2004 2200 14841 228966763 0.0012  86853166
   846  61 2005 2500 15559 345889717 0.0081 103029905
  2209 178 2003   NA    NA        NA     NA        NA
  2210 178 2004  200 45093        NA     NA  11668685
  2211 178 2005  250 47202    610500 0.1605  12813908
```

Then, I apply a formula to all the complete cases in the data so, for this particular example, I will get a matrix with 5 lines of results (and 2 results per observation) that I am showing down here:

```
   id    x  y
  606 8000 30
  844 1700 90
  845 8000 61
  846  400 82
 2211  600 30
```

So now, what I basically want is, only for rows in year 2005 in the dataframe, check where there is a matching (by id) in the matrix and modify a specific column in the dataframe (that I created before as “value”) with its corresponding result in the “y” column of the matrix. Consider here some points: (a) for the non complete cases it should offer NA, (b) I only want year 2005 to be modified; other years will be modified later with other follow up formulas that will offer a different matrix result. Given this, to my knowledge, functions like `merge`, `match`, `cbind` or `plyr` ones, will affect the whole column and I am not looking for that. Other options like `%in%` or `%l%` didn’t work neither, or I am using them mistakenly. This is what I tried so far with no success:

```
df$value [c(df$year==2005)]  <-  matrix[,3[matrix[,1]==df$id]]

df$value [c(df$year==2005)]  <-  matrix[,3][matrix[,1]==df$id]
```

Maybe a loop can be the solution but I am still learning how to build them and was unfruitful too.
Here the result that I would expect, for better understanding.

```
    id obs year   a1    a2        b1     b2         c value  
   604  43 2003   NA    NA        NA     NA        NA    NA
   605  43 2004   NA    NA        NA     NA        NA    NA
   606  43 2005 9000  6421   1748365 0.1616  36872152    30
   769  55 2003   NA    NA        NA     NA        NA    NA
   770  55 2004   NA    NA        NA     NA        NA    NA
   771  55 2005 2500 12449        NA     NA 125992307    NA
   844  61 2003 1800 11633 157977428 0.0089  69901689    NA
   845  61 2004 2200 14841 228966763 0.0012  86853166    NA
   846  61 2005 2500 15559 345889717 0.0081 103029905    82
  2209 178 2003   NA    NA        NA     NA        NA    NA
  2210 178 2004  200 45093        NA     NA  11668685    NA
  2211 178 2005  250 47202    610500 0.1605  12813908    30
```

Thanks a lot for any hint and keep on doing the great job. I was checking this web for about a year already and it helped me a lot!!!

Comment: something like `df[!is.na(df$a1) & df$year==2005 & df$id %in% lookup$id,]$a1 <- 
  lookup[lookup$id %in% df[!is.na(df$a1) & df$year==2005 & df$id %in% lookup$id,]$id,]$y`? Also, using a variable name like `matrix` is just asking for trouble on down the road, hence my use of `lookup` (which is also not optimal).

Comment: maybe check out [sqldf](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sqldf/sqldf.pdf)? I feel this question is so sql..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try: `df1` is the `data.frame` and `m1` matrix

```
  indx <- which(df1$year==2005)
```

#### Update

I guess I missed one of the conditions i.e. `complete.cases` (though in the example dataset, it didn't change the results).  The new `indx` should be

```
  indx <- which(df1$year==2005 & !rowSums(is.na(df1[-(1:3)]))) #inspired from @alexis_laz answer

  df1$value <- NA
  df1$value[indx[df1$id[indx] %in% m1[,"id"] ]] <- m1[, "y"][m1[,"id"] %in% df1$id[indx]]
   df1
  #     id obs year   a1    a2        b1     b2         c value
  #1   604  43 2003   NA    NA        NA     NA        NA    NA
  #2   605  43 2004   NA    NA        NA     NA        NA    NA
  #3   606  43 2005 9000  6421   1748365 0.1616  36872152    30
  #4   769  55 2003   NA    NA        NA     NA        NA    NA
  #5   770  55 2004   NA    NA        NA     NA        NA    NA
  #6   771  55 2005 2500 12449        NA     NA 125992307    NA
  #7   844  61 2003 1800 11633 157977428 0.0089  69901689    NA
  #8   845  61 2004 2200 14841 228966763 0.0012  86853166    NA
  #9   846  61 2005 2500 15559 345889717 0.0081 103029905    82
  #10 2209 178 2003   NA    NA        NA     NA        NA    NA
  #11 2210 178 2004  200 45093        NA     NA  11668685    NA
  #12 2211 178 2005  250 47202    610500 0.1605  12813908    30
```

#### data

```
 df1 <-   structure(list(id = c(604L, 605L, 606L, 769L, 770L, 771L, 844L, 
 845L, 846L, 2209L, 2210L, 2211L), obs = c(43L, 43L, 43L, 55L, 
 55L, 55L, 61L, 61L, 61L, 178L, 178L, 178L), year = c(2003L, 2004L, 
 2005L, 2003L, 2004L, 2005L, 2003L, 2004L, 2005L, 2003L, 2004L, 
 2005L), a1 = c(NA, NA, 9000L, NA, NA, 2500L, 1800L, 2200L, 2500L, 
 NA, 200L, 250L), a2 = c(NA, NA, 6421L, NA, NA, 12449L, 11633L, 
 14841L, 15559L, NA, 45093L, 47202L), b1 = c(NA, NA, 1748365L, 
 NA, NA, NA, 157977428L, 228966763L, 345889717L, NA, NA, 610500L
 ), b2 = c(NA, NA, 0.1616, NA, NA, NA, 0.0089, 0.0012, 0.0081, 
 NA, NA, 0.1605), c = c(NA, NA, 36872152L, NA, NA, 125992307L, 
 69901689L, 86853166L, 103029905L, NA, 11668685L, 12813908L)), .Names = c("id", 
 "obs", "year", "a1", "a2", "b1", "b2", "c"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
 -12L))

 m1 <- structure(c(606L, 844L, 845L, 846L, 2211L, 8000L, 1700L, 8000L, 
 400L, 600L, 30L, 90L, 61L, 82L, 30L), .Dim = c(5L, 3L), .Dimnames = list(
 NULL, c("id", "x", "y")))
```

Answer (score 2):

Using akrun's data, you could, also, use:

```
ifelse(df1$year == 2005 & rowSums(sapply(df1[-(1:3)], is.na)) == 0, 
       m1[match(df1$id, m1[, "id"]), "y"], 
       NA)
 #[1] NA NA 30 NA NA NA NA NA 82 NA NA 30
```

i.e. if the year is 2005 and there is no `NA`in the row, take the respective "y" from the matrix else `NA`.

Comment: do you always need an `else` with the `if`? Or can you just use `if`?

Comment: How would do this replacement in place? If trying to edit the values of the data.frame and not a vector? Could I just assign that vector to the column I want?

Comment: @RafaelMartins : You mean in `ifelse`? `ifelse` is not the classic control flow statement in R; it 's, just, a function with 3 arguments. If I understand your second comment correctly, I guess you, just, need to store the result in a new column as `dataframe$column = avector`

Answer (score 0):

If I was in your shoes, I probably will write a for loop and a function to loop through every record since it seems like they have several difference logic going on based on the condition.

Here is my understanding of your 'specification':

1. work on only on the rows which obeys certain criteria (year equals 2005 in this case) instead of `affecting the whole column`.

Here is some code, it is a bit long but I don't know if the idea of breaking the dataframe into two parts and then put them back together using melt/cast will be helpful:

```
mytext1 <- "id obs year   a1    a2        b1     b2         c
604  43 2003   NA    NA        NA     NA        NA
605  43 2004   NA    NA        NA     NA        NA
606  43 2005 9000  6421   1748365 0.1616  36872152
769  55 2003   NA    NA        NA     NA        NA
770  55 2004   NA    NA        NA     NA        NA
771  55 2005 2500 12449        NA     NA 125992307
844  61 2003 1800 11633 157977428 0.0089  69901689
845  61 2004 2200 14841 228966763 0.0012  86853166
846  61 2005 2500 15559 345889717 0.0081 103029905
2209 178 2003   NA    NA        NA     NA        NA
2210 178 2004  200 45093        NA     NA  11668685
2211 178 2005  250 47202    610500 0.1605  12813908"

mytext2 <- "id    x  y
606 8000 30
844 1700 90
845 8000 61
846  400 82
2211  600 30"

data.1 <- read.table(text=mytext1, header=TRUE)
data.2 <- read.table(text=mytext2, header=TRUE)
require(plyr)
require(reshape2)
a <- merge(x=subset(data.1, year==2005), y=data.2, by="id")
b <- subset(data.1, year!=2005)
a.new <- melt(a, id.vars=c('id'))
b.new <- melt(b, id.vars=c('id'))
result.new <- rbind(a.new, b.new)
result <- dcast(result.new, id ~ variable)
```

Now you have the result likes this:

```
> result
id obs year   a1    a2        b1     b2         c    x  y
1   604  43 2003   NA    NA        NA     NA        NA   NA NA
2   605  43 2004   NA    NA        NA     NA        NA   NA NA
3   606  43 2005 9000  6421   1748365 0.1616  36872152 8000 30
4   769  55 2003   NA    NA        NA     NA        NA   NA NA
5   770  55 2004   NA    NA        NA     NA        NA   NA NA
6   844  61 2003 1800 11633 157977428 0.0089  69901689   NA NA
7   845  61 2004 2200 14841 228966763 0.0012  86853166   NA NA
8   846  61 2005 2500 15559 345889717 0.0081 103029905  400 82
9  2209 178 2003   NA    NA        NA     NA        NA   NA NA
10 2210 178 2004  200 45093        NA     NA  11668685   NA NA
11 2211 178 2005  250 47202    610500 0.1605  12813908  600 30
```

You still need to change the name either in the end or before putting them back together.. :)